# Can Dell power vault nx 300 work without active directory?

Tags: active-directory, dell

I am struggling to find this solution...

Dell customer support is not helping with this issue. They are asking money for the support. I cant get any info from google regarding the configuration.

Comment: don't really know much about the device but since it arrives without knowledge of a domain existence then I'm sure it can work without AD. let me do some reading on the nx300

Comment: looks like there are two additions workgroup or not, which version do you have?

Answer (score 1):

It is just windows 2008 underneath.  Without AD it'll work but you'll have to sync local passwords up manually and some features eg. domain based DFS will be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell NX300 uses Windows Storage Server 2008.  Storage Server doesn't need to be joined to a domain to work, so there's no reason it can't run without active directory.

As JamesRyan mentioned, you'll be using local authentication on the NX300 then (likely a pain) or have to use some other method for authentication.

Features like SMB/CIFS file sharing and FCI will work, but you will lose domain-dependent technologies like DFS.